# transforming coordinates to a rotated coordinate system

Tags: math, geometry, rotation, transform, coordinate-systems

I am trying to convert the rotation and crop rectangle settings of an old graphics editor to new editor which uses different coordinate system than the old one. The following picture illustrates the problem:

[image: rectangles illustration]

All the rectangles have the same aspect ratio (e.g. 3:2), and all the coordinates are normalized across the edges (ie from 0 to 1 in both X and Y direction).

The old program saves the coordinates of corners of the blue rectangle C given in the coordinate system aligned with the green rectangle (with origin at A), and the angle of rotation of yellow rectangle.

The new program needs the coordinates of the corners of the blue rectangle in the coordinate system aligned with the yellow rectangle (with origin at B). How do I do the transformation from old to new?

This seems like a simple math problem, but it has been so many years since the math classes that I could not figure this out with pen-and-paper nor searching this site (many similar questions, but I could not find quite a matching one...)

Comment: I didn't probably describe the known variables clearly enough. Only the coordinates of the rectangle C and the angle of rotation from X axis (all in coordinate system A) are known. The coordinates of B are not known. however, it is known that the aspect ratio of A and B are both the same, and the B is the largest rectangle that can fit inside A. The rectangle C can actually be anywhere inside the rectangle A, and may have different aspect ratio.

Comment: Additional constraint which should make calculation of B easier: the rectangle B is centered inside the rectangle A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `c(0), c(1), c(2), c(3)` be the four corners of `C` and let `b(0)` be the corner B where B's coordinate system is located. Let `q` be the angle of rotation of the x-axis of B. All these angles and points must be given in the same coordinate system.

To find the coordinates of `c(i)` in B, rotate the vector `c(i) - b(0)` by the angle `q` (or `-q` depending on how things are measured). You can use a rotation matrix for this. Let `cq = cos(q)`, `sq = sin(q)`, and `(dx, dy) = c(i) - b(0)`. The coordinates of `c(i)` in B are then

[image: Product of the rotation matrix for q and (dx, dy)]

---

Let `c = (c(0) + c(2)) / 2` be the center of C. Let `S(s)` be the matrix that scales by `s` and let `R(q)` be the matrix that rotates by `q`. The corners of B are given by

```
b(i) = c + S(s) * R(q) * (c(i) - c)
```

The corners `a(0), a(1), a(2), a(3)` of the rectangle A are also known. We wish to determine the greatest possible value of the scaling parameter `s` such that all points `b(i)` of B are within the rectangle A.

I think the safest and simplest approach here is to consider relevant pairs of `b(i)` and `a(i)` and for such pairs compute the greatest value `s(i, j)` such that if `s = s(i, j)` then `b(i)` is within the corner region of `a(j)`.

Let `a(0)` and `a(2)` be opposite corners of A and let `c(0)` and `c(1)` be adjacent corners of C. Let `r(j) = a(j) - c` and `d(i) = R(q) * (c(i) - c)`.

Each diagonal `i` can be scaled by

```
s(i, j) = min (|r(j).x| / |d(i).x|, |r(j).y| / |d(i).y|)
```

before B moves outside the region defined by `r(j)`. Compute `s(i, j)` for `i = 0, 1` and `j = 0, 2` and let `s` be the minimum of those 4 values.

---

Depending on how `q` is measured you may need to apply a transformation `q' = atan2(kx * sin(q), ky * cos(q))` to `q` to account for issues of aspect ratio.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the whole problem, since b(0) is unknown (see my comment above). Still this was helpful, since now I understand this is actually two independent problems, and you answered the latter one. Now I must find out the coordinates of b(0) given the aspect ratio constraints of A and B, and then I can use your formula to transform any kind of C.

Comment: @JPK I've added an extended discussion.

Comment: Your answer seems to be assuming rectangle C would always have the same aspect ratio as A and B, which isn't always true.   However, replacing C with the rotated A, then finding the s with your algorithm, I can calculate the b(i), after which I can rotate the coordinates of C.  Thank you very much for your help!